# How do I detect MIME type via a file handle in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm on 5.4 and looking to detect a mime type from my file handle. I know I can save off a file and then use functions by passing strings, but we want to avoid using strings. So is there a way without any strings?

Comment: [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)?

Comment: There's no way to do this directly from a file handle, but you can do it from a buffer (string) or file path. Can't you use either of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a file handle or a string, pass an [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php). Using this, you get OO access to the file without directly calling file system functions. Functions that require a pathname can still by used by calling ->getRealPath() on the object.

```
$finfo     = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
$mime_type = $finfo->file( $fileObject->getRealPath() );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP installation supports [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php):

```
$finfo = new finfo;
$mime = $finfo->file($file, FILEINFO_MIME);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Where `$file` would be the full path to the file. `$mime` will then contain it's MIME type, for example 'image/jpeg' for a JPG image or 'text/x-php' for a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`fileinfo`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php)

```
$fileinfo = finfo_file($finfo, $file, FILEINFO_MIME);     
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Or, you could do it the object-oriented way:

```
$finfo = new finfo();
$file = '/path/to/file/';
$fileinfo = $finfo->file($file, FILEINFO_MIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [stream_get_meta_data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data) to extract `uri`

```php
$mime = mime_content_type(
    stream_get_meta_data($fh)['uri']
);
```

Where `$fh` is our filehandle

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK there's nothing inside a file content bytes that specifically tell the mime type. You have two options:

1. Detect the contents inspecting the bytes (actually I don't think this should be considered an option, given the difficulty and the performance implications involved).
2. Detect the mime type inspecting the file extension (if such extension exists): this method isn't error-proof, but is the accepted way of doing this (IMO). If the file haven't any extension, then you have a problem that can't be easily solved.